# Efficient way to ASCII encode UTF-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ascii, punycode

I'm looking for a simple and efficient way to store UTF-8 strings in ASCII-7. With efficient I mean the following:

- all ASCII alphanumeric chars in the input should stay the same ASCII alphanumeric chars in the output
- the resulting string should be as short as possible
- the operation needs to be reversable without any data loss
- the resulting ASCII string should be case insensitive
- there should be no restriction on the input length
- the whole UTF-8 range should be allowed

My first idea was to use Punycode (IDNA) as it fits the first four requirements, but it fails at the last two.

Can anyone recommend an alternative encoding scheme? Even better if there's some code available to look at.

Comment: What do you mean by "all ASCII char in the input should stay ASCII chars in the output"? And are you asking for something that is a 7-bit encoding?

Comment: I updated the first point to be more clear. I also forgot to mention that I'd like to have case insensitive output which seems to rule out UTF-7.

Comment: When you say "the resulting ASCII string should be case insensitive" what do you mean? String are just strings, they aren't case sensitive or insensitive. Do you mean that it should be all lowercase? All uppercase?

Comment: It shouldn't matter when the case get's mangled. Eg. when the encoded string contains uppercase letter and somehow get's lowercased decoding should still remain the same input string. This of course does not affect the letters that where left untouched from the input which will always be lowercase.

Eg. in punycode xn--bcher-kva is the same as xn--bcher-KVA.

Comment: So you're saying that if the string storage mechanism modifies the case of the encoded string, then the resulting decoded string will still be byte-for-byte identical to the source string? So you don't care whether the ASCII alphanumeric characters in the source are preserved ASCII alphanumeric characters in the encoded string? It's just the decoded string that matters?

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect this new understanding.

Comment: What language are your working in? There are several scripts that will convert Unicode (utf-8) to ascII.

Answer (score 4):

[UTF-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7), or, slightly less transparent but more widespread, [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

> all ASCII chars in the input should stay ASCII chars in the output

(Obviously not fully possible as you need at least *one* character to act as an escape.)

Comment: You're reading the requirement as saying that ASCII chars in the input stay as *the same* ASCII chars in the output. That may be what he intended (in which case you're clearly correct) but it's not what he actually said -- and an encoding that fits the stated requirement is certainly possible.

Comment: Heh. Yes I meant ASCII chars should stay the same char. UTF-7 looks like a good candidate. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Andreas Gohr - UTF-7 does not preserve the ASCII range from modification.

Comment: UTF-7 seems to be case-sensitive which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Since ASCII covers the full range of 7-bit values, an encoding scheme that preserves all ASCII characters, is 7-bits long, and encodes the full Unicode range is not possible.

Edited to add:

I think I understand your requirements now. You are looking for a way to encode UTF-8 strings in a seven-bit code, in which, if that encoded string were interpreted as ASCII text, then the case of the alphabetic characters may be arbitrarily modified, and yet the decoded string will be byte-for-byte identical to the original.

If that's the case, then your best bet would probably be just to encode the binary representation of the original as a string of hexadecimal digits. I know you are looking for a more compact representation, but that's a pretty tall order given the other constraints of the system, unless some custom encoding is devised.

Since the hexadecimal representation can encode any arbitrary binary values, it might be possible to shrink the string by compressing them before taking the hex values.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about non-standard schemes - [MECE](http://iquit.leadhoster.com/quote.htm)

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding or numeric character references are two possible options.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the distribution of characters in your strings.

Quoted-printable is good for mostly-ASCII strings because there's no overhead except with '=' and control characters.  However, non-ASCII characters take an inefficient 6-12 bytes each, so if you have a lot of those, you'll want to consider UTF-7 or Base64 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Punycode is used for IDNA, but you can use it outside the restrictions imposed by it

Per se, Punycode doesn't fail your last 2 requirements:

```
>>> import sys
>>> _ = ("\U0010FFFF"*10000).encode("punycode")
>>> all(chr(c).encode("punycode") for c in range(sys.maxunicode))
True
```

(for idna, python supplies another homonymous encoding)

obviously, if you don't nameprep the input, the encoded string isn't strictly case-insensitive anymore... but if you supply only lowercase (or if you don't care about the decoded case) you should be good to go