# how to insert and read utf-8 text on RecordStore

Tags: java, java-me

how can i insert a `UTF-8` String into RecordStore and read this as a `UTF-8` String ?

thanks

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567318/efficient-way-to-ascii-encode-utf-8

Comment: i read your link content, but i can't solve my problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//write

ByteArrayOutputStream boStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream doStream = new DataOutputStream(boStream);
doStream.writeUTF(myString);
temp.addRecord(boStream.toByteArray(), 0, boStream.size());
```

```
//read

ByteArrayInputStream biStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(temp.getRecord(id));
DataInputStream diStream = new DataInputStream(biStream);
myString = diStream.readUTF();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the handle wrong on the question. `RecordStore` still store byte arrays. What you need to do is convert it into a byte array and back again. Just use `string.getBytes()` and then store it like that, and then the opposite is `String str = new String(bytes);`. Hope that helps. The default charset of either J2ME or J2SE is UTF-8, so there's no messing about there.